# Which key should I use to sign google map for Android App to be uploaded on GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-maps, android-keystore

I have an Android app where I am using google maps to display geofence. I have used GooglePlay App signing process, so now if I want to use google map in my app which key(upload or private key) should I use to generate google API key.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Documentation
If you want to Integrate Google Map in your App follow this URL[Google Map Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

If You want to restrict your API Key for  only used by your App then follow this URL[Restrict your API Key](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/signup)

You have to Generate your SHA 1 key and Add in your Google API console

Answer (score 0):

You should use restricted key to display.